# Regular Expression Difficulties

Tags: python, regex

So this is the link I have to extract:

http://www.hrmagazine.co.uk/article-details/finance-sector-dominates-working-families-benchmark

And this is what I have currently

```
.+\/article-details\/.+\-.+\-.+\-.+\-.+\-.+$
```

The issue, however, is it extracts any number of words and hyphens after the "/article-details/" part, rather than specifically 6 word titles with hyphens replacing the spaces above. So it would accept a bad result

```
http://www.hrmagazine.co.uk/article-details/finance-sector-dominates-working-families-benchmark-test
```

When I need it to only accept links like this format

```
http://www.hrmagazine.co.uk/article-details/one-two-three-four-five-six
```

What's the correct regular expression for this type of website? The current extractor I have in Scrapy/Spyder is the following

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['.+\/article-details\/.+\-.+\-.+\-.+\-.+\-.+$']), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)
```

Comment: Try `//a[count(tokenize(substring-after(@href, "article-details/"), "-"))=6]/@href` to extract link reference that contains 5 hyphens

Comment: Where does that statement go in reference to the problem? And that doesn't look to be in the format of a regular expression...

Comment: You marked your question with "XPath" tag. This is the XPath

Comment: Ah. Whoops. I changed it to the regular expression tag now.

Comment: Extract it from *what*?

Answer (score 0):

Each of those `.+` in your regex can match any number of ANY character - including hyphens.  So your overall regex is just requiring a minimum of 5 hyphens, not an exact count.  Use `[^-]+` to match only non-hyphen characters.

Note that none of those backslashes in your regex are accomplishing anything - in no case is the following character something requiring escaping.  Even if they were, you'd need to double the backslashes, or use a raw string `r'whatever'`, so that the backslashes are being interpreted by the `re` module, rather than Python's string literal parsing rules.

Comment: So... what's the correct regular expression I should be using then?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `.` with something like `[a-z]`; `.` will also match hyphens, which is why its matching an unlimited number of words:

```
.+\/article-details\/[a-z]+\-[a-z]+\-[a-z]+\-[a-z]+\-[a-z]+\-[a-z]+$
```

If you need to match things like numbers, add them to the brackets as well (`[a-z0-9]`, etc.).